# How to remove product number count in the category within the sidebar woo commence

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I’m trying to remove the number count next to my products.
I’ve tried the snippet code that’s circling around the net and tried css editing with the code but with no avail.
I’m using Astra theme and I’m working on the site locally.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Probably solvable but like, can you include your code?  Or a link to the site or some more specifics?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.